# How can we write a test class for class containing the Database.insertImmediate method?

Tags: unit-test, big-object, stubapi

I have a class which archives sobject records as big objects. This includes the method Database.insertImmediate(). As this database method counts as a callout, it seems it cannot be covered during testing as it returns the error:

> You have uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback before calling out

The only option I can see is to exclude it during testing by using:

```
if(!Test.isRunningTest()){
   Database.insertImmediate(sobjList);
}
```

But this doesn't seem ideal and doesn't really test the functionality. I've read about using the StubAPI but is it possible to mock a Database.insertImmediate() call?

If so, how can I do this? If not, what would be the recommended way to test a class which includes `Database.insertImmediate()`?

(Apologies if there is already an answer on this specific query - I have looked through the forums quite extensively)

Thanks
Tom

EDIT:

```
public class ExampleBigObjectBatchClass implements Database.Batchable<sObject>{
   public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC)
    {
        return Database.getQueryLocator(taskQueryString);
    }
    
    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sObject> scope){
        List<Task> tasks = (List<Task>) scope;
        List<BigObject> bgList = new List<BigObject>();

        for(Task tsk : tasks){
            bgList.add(
                new BigObject(
                    // map task fields to big object fields
                );
            );
        }

        List<Database.SaveResult> saveResults;
        if(!Test.isRunningTest()){
            saveResults = Database.insertImmediate(bgList);
        } else {
            // in test class, I'm mocking Save Results to simulate success/failure
            saveResults = SaveResultManager.saveResults(new List<Database.SaveResult>());
        }
        for (Database.SaveResult result : saveResults) {
            if (!result.isSuccess()) {
                for (Database.Error error : result.getErrors()) {
                    // log errors
                }
            } else {
                // do something for success
            }
        }

        // update task records
    }
}
```

Comment: You should show the class that you are testing as there may be a way to restructure it to be testable

Comment: Hi @cropredy, thanks for the reply, I can't show the actual class as it has some identifying bits in it but I've added an example class which is basically the same functionality in a simpler way.

Comment: OK, have you tried just testing the execute() method passing in Task SObjects (rather than DML'd Tasks) - I can't tell from the above if the BigObject needs a valid Task.Id